# Removing a particular polygon from maps data

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am generating polygons using addGeoJson method but I am not sure how can I remove a particular polygon later when needed. Here is my code

```
var __layers;
 var layer = new google.maps.Data();
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            success:function(data) {
                __layers = layer.addGeoJson(data);
                layer.setMap(map1);
                layer.setStyle(style);
            }
        });
```

I am trying to remove data like this but its not working

```
map1.data.remove(__layers[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way _layers has been initialized looks to be the culprit here. You may either try layer.setMap(null) or modify your code as following

```
var __layers = [];
 var layer = new google.maps.Data();
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            success:function(data) {
                __layers.push(layer.addGeoJson(data));
                layer.setMap(map1);
                layer.setStyle(style);
            }
        });
```

And then use

```
map1.data.remove(__layers.pop());
```